# Change position of an element - responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

How can i change the position of an element from being left to being right in a smaller screen?

This is for wider screens:

```
.nav {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5%;
}
```

and i would like to position it right:10px for the smaller screen.

Thanks.

===========================================================

I made a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/romullus/5u64M/

===========================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the break points this way(assuming 600 px is the breakpoint between small screen and large screen)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
   .nav {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5%;
 }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .nav {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;

 }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mj3K/)

**update 1**

In reference to the updated fiddle provided in the question the newer working code on the above logic will be

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .social-nav {
            position:absolute;
            right: 10px;
        }
        .social-nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .social-nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            display:block;
            background: #393939;
            padding:10px 10px 5px 10px;
            margin: 1px;
            opacity: .5;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        }
        .social-nav ul li:hover {
            opacity: .8;
            background:#fff;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .social-nav {
            background:#000;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 5%;
        }
        .social-nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .social-nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            display:table-cell;
            float: left;
            background: #393939;
            padding:100px 10px 5px 10px;
            margin: 1px;
            opacity: .5;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        }
        .social-nav ul li:hover {
            opacity: .8;
            background:#fff;
        }
        .social-nav ul li a {
            color:#fff;
        }
    }
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mj3K/2/)

Comment: thank you for the answer! i made this but its still on the left side... i really have no idea whats the problem...

Comment: @romullus: Hi , you were just missing the closing curly braces in the proper place. I have updated my answer and created a new fiddle. Just check.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set a media query for the *size*, as you would like the browser,to shift the element from left to right  at different resolutions .

```
   @media (min-width: 780px) and (max-width: 980px) {
   // CSS definition for element(s) at this resolution 

}
```

Of course you will change the min and max to your desired size or you can just set a min width.

Comment: yes... i made this already. but in this media query that i set for smaller screen, my element still is position left altough i was puting right:10px; any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the viewport meta tag in your header? Your media queries wont work properly without it.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```