# Changing the position of css element based on screen size

Tags: html, css

```
Can we change the position of anchor tag which is active and inactive based on screen size using css?

    <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                  <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
                  <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
                  <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
              </div>
          </div>
     <div class="mydiv">
              <h2>Let's Be Friends</h2>
    </div>
    CSS:
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 840px) {
      #status-buttons a.active {
        margin-top:500px;
      }
.mydiv{
margin-top:10px;
}

  /* Styles */
}...
```

I want mydiv class to be on top of that  tag when that particular link is active for example if profile link is active I want to change the position of mydiv class here position means not fixed, relative etc... I want to change the margin-top,margin-left etc..

Comment: yes you can using media queries below link should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540763/change-position-of-an-element-responsive-website

Comment: Please share your code you are trying?

Comment: why is this upvoted ? this is not a question suitable for SO . please read how to ask questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: HTML: <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
          </div>
      </div>                                  CSS:@media only screen 
and (max-width : 840px) {
  #status-buttons a.active {
    margin-top:10px;
  }
  /* Styles */
}

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks some details to give you a really detailed answer. `position: fixed` might work

> [...] position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. 
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control)

But `position` does not apply to inline elements such as `<a>`, hence you will need to position the surrounding container or set the a itself to `display: block`. The position will then change based on the size of the screen. Also, `position: relative` might work along with viewport units (vw / vh standing for viewport height / viewport width).